# How to go about finding cells on a grid that are intersected by a straight line?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Starting with a grid of discretized positions and given a start and end points for a line segment, how would you go about finding the cells on that grid that are intersected by this line segment?

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

xd = np.arange(0, 20, 1)
yd = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

grid = np.full((len(xd), len(yd)), False)

set_some_grid_cells_to_True(grid)

x_start = 2.7
x_end = 4.9

y_start = 1.5
y_end = 5.7

# Here I would like to check if the straight line given by those two 
# endpoints intersects any of the cells on the grid that have the value True
```

I'd like this to work in a systematic way, independent of any start or end points and independent of the grid resolution.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: please provide a example

Comment: Post a code with the initialized grid and two points. Then we can help you.

Comment: @Pitto I've edited my question. Sorry for not making it clear enough in the first place.

Comment: There are many graphics algorithms that solve the cell-intersection problem.  Start with [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) and post again if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is my try to your question

please find explanation on the comment

Note: it assumes grid ends at 9 in y direction

```py
import numpy as np

xd = np.arange(0, 20, 1)
yd = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

grid = np.random.choice([True, False], (len(xd), len(yd)))

x_start = 2.7
x_end = 4.9

y_start = 1.5
y_end = 5.7


## find line equation
m = (y_end - y_start)/(x_end-x_start)
c = y_start - m*x_start

## find y value of line at all starting x of grid
y_line = m*xd + c

## find y index of cell at which line cross at each start of grid
insert_ind = yd.searchsorted(y_line)

## find x and y index of grid where line intersect
x_index, y_index = zip(*[(i,ind) for i, ind in enumerate(insert_ind) if (ind>0 and ind<len(yd)-1)])

## create grid with all False for intersecting and set intersecting cells to True
intersecting_grid = np.full((len(xd), len(yd)), False)
intersecting_grid[x_index, y_index] = True

result = intersecting_grid & grid

print(result)
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe `xd` could start from floor(x_start) to ceil(x_end)` in `y_line = m*xd + c` this line.

Comment: ya if you want to check intersection for that line segment only, may be this is what the user want. This code checks intersection with line represented by the start and end point. ya may be

Answer (score -1):

There is special algorithm intended for retrieving all cells between two points:
Woo and Amanatides grid traversal algorithm ["Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm..."](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf)

[Example of implementation in C](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)

Illustration shows touched cells:

[image]